# How to increase / optimise dimension of pdt / html to avoid overflowing of tables with Quarto in R?

Tags: r, quarto

I am exporting a document in html format using Quarto in R with the following YAML content

```
---
title: "Tirzepatide_dosresmeta"
format: pdf
editor: visual
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
execute:
  echo: false
---
```

Now, the exported html document has multiple tables with 7 columns and 3 rows. The first 6 columns and 3 rows appear normally, however, the last column (and all the rows for this column) come below the upper one. So, it looks like a 3*6 table followed by a 1*6 table. Moreover, this also doesn't allow copy pasting into my final MS Word file where I am typing the report and interpretation. Is there any way to correct this?

An example table is

```
$result_table
  lin.dose lin.pred lin.ci.lb lin.ci.ub spl_bin.pred spl_bin.ci.lb
1        5     1.00      1.00      1.00         1.00          1.00
2       10     0.94      0.82      1.08         0.93          0.65
3       15     0.88      0.67      1.17         0.88          0.67
  spl_bin.ci.ub
1          1.00
2          1.33
3          1.18
```

**Potential solutions tried:**
I tried changing html to pdf or docx and the problem continued.

I tried changing part of YAML from

```
format: pdf
```

to

```
output: 
 html_document
  output.width = 100%
```

and it did not work (even with 150%).

I somehow feel exporting tables and results using officer to ms word file seems more presentable (where feasible)

Does anyone know how to avoid this overflowing of table?